# Classico "Execution of C:\ . . . failed" no codeblocks

Tags: c

Estou tendo esse problema no codeblocks em que quando tento rodar qualquer programa nele recebo

*Execution of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe "C:\Users\cliente\Desktop\Programacao\C\teste.exe"' in 'C:\Users\cliente\Desktop\Programacao\C' failed.*

Já consultei várias dúvidas, inclusive aqui no stack, mas nenhuma das soluções propostas deram certo. Já comparei minhas configurações com de outros computadores e não tem nada fora de ordem, reinstalei várias vezes, e nada.

Não entendo por que ele não consegue encontrar o exe e rodar o programa, se é que esse é realmente o problema. Eu já tentei tudo que me veio na cabeça, e tudo que as soluções da internet me ofereceram, se alguém tiver qualquer ideia por favor me ajude.

Comment: Veja se o CodeBlocks não esta preparando o ambiente de execução errado para executar seu programa. Se estiver errado, o Windows não vai conseguir encontrar as DLLs que o programa precisa. Veja a configuração de ambiente dentro do CodeBlocks.

Comment: já tentou configurar o compilador corretamente?

Comment: Hmmm [desliga o teu antivirus???](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,18517.msg127768.html?PHPSESSID=lcegcjc2ni7iiubji19aoi8hf1#msg127768)

Comment: Vinícius, dei uma olhada e ao meu ver está tudo no lugar. Mas por favor, como posso fazer uma verificação mais profunda?*******
Rhayden, até onde pesquisei e configurei, o compilador está com as configurações padrões, não só do que é esperado (ou seja, o padrão) como de outros computadores. Como você configurou seu compilador corretamente? Talvez tenha algum passo que me seja útil.*******
pmg, Já desinstalei o antivirus. Até agora nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema! O CB estava instalado no ...(x86) eu apenas reinstalei em outro diretório, em seguida compilou e rodou normalmente usando o F9 !